# How to create setup file in Visual Studio 2017 with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, setup-project

After creating setup file on another computer, the database does not work. I really need to know how to build a setup file with SQL Server database included.

```
string conn=(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\PejTextNum2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this link from [Installshield](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield21helplib/helplibrary/SQL-CreatingSampProjSQLServer.htm?)

Just make sure you're not using Express Edition.

This works for me using SQL Server 2014.